# Symfony2 Class Loader loadClass()

Tags: php, classloader, symfony-components

I have a problem with a Symfony2 ClassLoader Component.

Start code:

```
    require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

    use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

    $loader = new UniversalClassLoader();

    $loader->registerNamespace('MyClass', 'src');
    $loader->useIncludePath(true);
    $loader->register();
```

My folder structure:

-src
--->MyClass
------->MyClass1.php **(MyClass\MyClass1)**
------->MyClass2.php **(MyClass\MyClass2)**

If I try to include a class, the class is not loaded, for example:

```
use MyClass\SimpleClass1;
$SimpleClass1 = new MyClass\SimpleClass1\Class1();
```

but if I use the method loadClass() working:

```
$loader->loadClass("MyClass\\SimpleClass1");
use MyClass\SimpleClass1;
$SimpleClass1 = new MyClass\SimpleClass1\Class1();
```

Comment: Where does all this `SimpleClass1` stuff come from? All I see are `MyClass\MyClass1` and `MyClass\MyClass2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, you use MyClass\SimpleClass1\Class1. The configured path for that class is `src/MyClass/SimpleClass1/Class1.php`, which does not exists. (btw, the use statement is useless there)

Your second example shows MyClass\SimpleClass1, which is -as you can see- different from your first example.